# Object reference not set to an instance of an object- Linked List Example

Tags: c#

I am seeing following errors :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object!
>
> Check to determinate if the object is null before calling the method!

I made a small test program for Sorted Linked Lists.
Here is the code where the error comes!

```
    public void Insert(double data)
    {
        Link newLink = new Link(data);
        Link current = first;
        Link previous = null;

        if (first == null)
        {
            first = newLink;
        }
        
        else
        {
            while (data > current.DData && current != null)
            {
                previous = current;
                current = current.Next;
            }

            previous.Next = newLink;
            newLink.Next = current;
        }
    }
```

It says that the current referenc is null `while (data > current.DData && current != null)`, but I assigned it: `current = first;`

The rest is the complete code of the Program!

```
class Link
{
    double dData;
    Link next=null;

    public Link Next
    {
        get { return next; }
        set { next = value; }
    }

    public double DData
    {
        get { return dData; }
        set { dData = value; }
    }

    public Link(double dData)
    {
        this.dData = dData;
    }


    public void DisplayLink()
    { 
    Console.WriteLine("Link : "+ dData);
    }

}

class SortedList
{
    Link first;

    public SortedList()
    { 
        first = null;
    }

    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return (this.first == null);
    }

    public void Insert(double data)
    {
        Link newLink = new Link(data);
        Link current = first;
        Link previous = null;

        if (first == null)
        {
            first = newLink;
        }
        
        else
        {
            while (data > current.DData && current != null)
            {
                previous = current;
                current = current.Next;
            }

            previous.Next = newLink;
            newLink.Next = current;
        }
    }

    public Link Remove()
    {
        Link temp = first;
        first = first.Next;
        return temp;
    }

    public void DisplayList()
    {
        Link current;
        current = first;

        Console.WriteLine("Display the List!");
        
        while (current != null)
        {
            current.DisplayLink();
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }
}

class SortedListApp
{
    public void TestSortedList()
    {
        SortedList newList = new SortedList();
        newList.Insert(20);
        newList.Insert(22);
        newList.Insert(100);
        newList.Insert(1000);
        newList.Insert(15);
        newList.Insert(11);

        newList.DisplayList();
        newList.Remove();
        newList.DisplayList();

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that `first` isn't `null`? (It seems to me that in an empty list it would be.)

Comment: Also, conditions like `data > current.DData && current != null` are *short-circuiting* from left to right. That means that `data > current.DDAta` is evaluated **before** `current != null`. The consequence is that if `current` is null, the combined expression will crash despite the `current != null` check, because the latter happens too late.

Comment: while (current != null && data > current.DData)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are perhaps assuming that the while loop is breaking on the first iteration which it's not it's the assignment in the while loop that eventually breaks it.

Eventually current is NULL based on your code, you even test for it - change it to this and it should be fine:

```
while (current != null && data > current.DData)
{
    previous = current;
    current = current.Next;
}
```

Comment: Thanks now I realize what the problem was, and now it sorts the list Fine!

Comment: no worries, could you please mark the answer as correct (if it is indeed correct). Cheers Rob

Answer (score 1):

Agree that you have done

```
current = first;
```

but then the beginning of your class first is null

```
class SortedList
{
    Link first;
```

please assign something to `first` else it will be null